# How to get a list of Lat Longs of a certain type using Google Places API without double requesting?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, location, google-places-api

**This is my code**

```
mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions("Supermarket", null, null).addOnSuccessListener {
        it.forEach {
            it.placeId?.let {
                mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById(it).addOnSuccessListener {
                    val marker = it[0].latLng
                    val name = it[0].name.toString()
                    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(marker).title(name))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For every supermarket it finds it has to request again to get the lat long as this information isn't included on the autocomplete prediction, only the place id.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save the double call as far as I can tell, but since you are getting back a list you can save the n number of calls by using the getPlaceById(String... placeIds) call.

```
mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions("Supermarket", null, null).addOnSuccessListener {
    it.map{ it.placeId}.filterNotNull().toTypedArray().let {
        mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById(*it).addOnSuccessListener {
            it.forEach{
                val marker = it.latLng
                val name = it.name.toString()
                mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(marker).title(name))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this might be the best possible way.

Comment: You can improve a little by putting up a on disk cache for the already resolved place (using Room for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It worked fine.

```
  mGeoDataClient?.getAutocompletePredictions("Supermarket", null, null)?.addOnSuccessListener{
        it.forEach { prediction ->
            val placeId = prediction.placeId
            val pendingResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient!!, placeId)
            pendingResult.setResultCallback {  placeBuffer->
                val place = placeBuffer.get(0)
                val marker = place.latLng
                val name = place.name.toString()
                mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(marker).title(name))
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is how my `mGoogleApiClient` initializes:

```
  private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null

  mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build()
```

Hope it can help you.